# My discord bot naturally has the DM option blocked, no matter what I try

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

So, eversince I started programming my discord bots, one thing has been bugging me. They all work fine, except for my main bot, Arctic. Arctic has it's DM blocked, and all my other bots with the same exact code run the DM messages just fine.     [Other Bot's DM working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C25m.png)
So I tried one experiment, I put the Token of the bot that had the dm function working into the bot that didn't have it working, and boom, no problems. But then, when I changed to the exact same configs as before (Same bot name, avatar, etc) it stopped working AGAIN...       [Blocked messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYClr.png)
I definetly think that it's not because of the code, but an error in the developer menu, so please help!

Here's my discord developer page, for reference [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh6CM.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WxRl.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0fzk.png)

Comment: Can we have some screens of your Discord developper portal panel?

Comment: @Florian Kamps It's done!

Comment: So, turns out you need the bot to be in at least two discord servers of your own? I don't know how that works, but when I had him on two different servers, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

*wish i could just comment*
Did you give the bot token to someone else? There is a small chance your bot is working from 2 computers at the same time (had this issue as well. The result was to have 2 outputs from every single comment/funtion/whatevere. Turned out my programmer friend had it running on his background). What i would suggest is to regenerate your key and put it back in your code.